# Unity 5 Randomly generated moving objects that slowly approach

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this code is suppose to generate randomly placed clouds and planes in the distance that will fly towards you while the objective is to dodge them, however it just spawns random planes that don't move. It just gradually spawns them closer to your plane and keeps spawning them even if it goes past it, while the ones previously spawned stay in the same spot, so it's just a trail of non-moving planes, how would I code it so they approach me? Anything helps, thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CloudGen : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject cloud;
    public GameObject enemy;

    int firstRand;
    int secondRand;
    int distance = 12;
    int time = 0;


    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Vector3 intPos;


    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("left") || Input.GetButtonDown ("right")) 
        {
            firstRand = Random.Range (1, 3);
            if(firstRand == 1)
            {
                secondRand = Random.Range (1, 3);
                GameObject cloudInt = Instantiate (cloud) as GameObject;
                for (int i = 0; i < secondRand; i++) 
                {
                    intPos = new Vector3 (Random.RandomRange(1, 4), 0, distance);
                    cloudInt.transform.position = intPos;
                    cloudInt.transform.Translate (distance, 0, 0);
                    distance -= 1;
                }
            }
            if (firstRand == 2) 
            {
                secondRand = Random.Range (1, 8);

                for (int i = 0; i < secondRand; i++) 
                {
                    intPos = new Vector3 (Random.RandomRange(1, 4), 0, distance);                   }
                    GameObject enemyInt = Instantiate (enemy) as GameObject;
                    enemyInt.transform.position = intPos;
                    enemyInt.transform.Translate (distance, 0, 0);
                    distance -= 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are doing is instantiate an object (cloud or enemy), move it to 'intPos' and move it 'distance' in the x-cordinate (in a single step). There is no code to tell the cloud or enemy to come towards player.